# Помогите разобраться как работает код, цикл for

Tags: python, for

задание: вывести все уникальные элементы списка:

```
a = [6, 9, 6, 23, 12, 19, 14, 26]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if i != j and a[i] == a[j]:
            break
    else:
        print(a[i], end=' ')
```

как я понял вложенный for позволяет сравнивать первый элемент списка с остальными, потом 2й и т.д.

в этой строчке if i != j and a[i] == a[j]:  мне не ясно, первое неравенство это сравнивает индексы а через "and" значения, или наоборот.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да вы правильно написали, i**f i != j and a[i] == a[j]: сравнивает индексы а через "and" значения**

Вот только скажем можно обойтись вложенного цикла

К примеру

```
a = [6, 9, 6, 23, 12, 19, 14, 26]
c = set()
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.add(a[i])

print(list(c))
```

Минус такого подхода, что он создает дополнительное место.

**UPD, после общения в комментария выяснилось, что в вопросе неправильно сформирован вопрос**

Сам текст ПРАВИЛЬНОГО вопроса

> Дан список. Выведите те его элементы, которые встречаются в списке
> только один раз. Элементы нужно выводить в том порядке, в котором они
> встречаются в списке.)

Код привидённый ниже не нарушает порядок и выводит значения, которые предоставленны только 1 раз

```py
    a = [6, 9, 6, 23, 12, 19, 14, 26]
    for i in a:
        if a.count(i) == 1:
            print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: Ваш код можно сократить до print(list(set(a))

Comment: по условию задачи(моя ошибка в описании, должны выводиться только уникальные элементы), дублированные элементы выводиться не должны, скажем из списка 1 1 2 2 3 4 4, должно вывести только 3, так что set() отпадает

Comment: @Leonfirebutton Почему с введёнными данными (1 1 2 2 3 4 4) должно вывестись только 3 значения ??? Берём в руки карандаш, бумагу и пишем на листочке, затем вычеркиваем дубликаты, что получается ? Правильно 1,2,3,4, где тут 3 значения ? В упор не вижу.

Comment: я старался понять как работает тот код что я привел., меня заинтересовал ваш, я его проверил, работает иначе, (условие задачи полностью: Дан список. Выведите те его элементы, которые встречаются в списке только один раз. Элементы нужно выводить в том порядке, в котором они встречаются в списке.)

Comment: Из условия задачи задание: вывести все уникальные элементы списка. Код приведённый выше как раз это и делает, выводит уникальные значение. Так прошу прощения, а вы можете изначально вопрос нормально сформировать ? Ваш изначальный и дополненный в комментариях это две разные задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос "Помогите разобраться как работает код, цикл for".

Из данного списка a = [6, 9, 6, 23, 12, 19, 14, 26], вернет:
9, 23, 12, 19, 14, 26. 6-ка дублирующийся элемент его не выводит

Изменим для наглядности список, с дублиирующими элементами [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]. Данный код выводит только значение 3 (индекс = 4) из списка . Добавим print в каждом цикле for чтобы увидеть каждую итерацию циклов:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
for i in range(len(list)):
    print("i :", list[i], "index of i:", i)
    for j in range(len(list)):
        print("j:", list[j], "index of j:", j)
        if i != j and list[i] == list[j]:
            break
    else:
        print("print from else:", list[i])
```

итерация выглядит так:

i : 1 index of i: 0

j: 1 index of j: 0

j: 1 index of j: 1

i : 1 index of i: 1

j: 1 index of j: 0

i : 2 index of i: 2

j: 1 index of j: 0

j: 1 index of j: 1

j: 2 index of j: 2

j: 2 index of j: 3

i : 2 index of i: 3

j: 1 index of j: 0

j: 1 index of j: 1

j: 2 index of j: 2

i : 3 index of i: 4

j: 1 index of j: 0

j: 1 index of j: 1

j: 2 index of j: 2

j: 2 index of j: 3

j: 3 index of j: 4

j: 4 index of j: 5

j: 4 index of j: 6

print from else: 3

i : 4 index of i: 5

j: 1 index of j: 0

j: 1 index of j: 1

j: 2 index of j: 2

j: 2 index of j: 3

j: 3 index of j: 4

j: 4 index of j: 5

j: 4 index of j: 6

i : 4 index of i: 6

j: 1 index of j: 0

j: 1 index of j: 1

j: 2 index of j: 2

j: 2 index of j: 3

j: 3 index of j: 4

j: 4 index of j: 5

как работает:

- на первых четырех элементах списка срабаытвает break, когда находится дублирующий элемент, и только когда очередь дошла до 3-ки, вложенный for проходит все итерации c 3-кой и потом переходит первый раз к дополнитеьному условию else
- на повторяющихся элементах срабытывает break и for начинает следующую итерацию ничего не выводя)

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите